# iterating over yaml data in middleman template

Tags: ruby, sinatra, yaml, padrino, middleman

I have a list of projects in a yaml file which i'd like to dynamically loop thru for a template in a middleman app but am unsure how or if I even can/should do it more dynamically.

I have:

```
data.projects.each do |f|
  proxy "/work/#{f[:name].parameterize}.html", "/work/template.html", 
    :locals => { name: f[:name], client: f[:client], ... } #would like to dynamically pull in keys as locals.
end

ignore "/work/template.html"
```

Yaml:

```
-  name: Acme Website
   client: Acme Inc
   overview: "Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet wafer gummi bears pudding applicake. Jujubes brownie powder. Sweet roll powder gingerbread gummies. Cupcake ice cream sweet roll pie lollipop. Jelly-o jelly-o apple pie chupa chups jelly jujubes gingerbread. Icing carrot cake powder chupa chups. Pudding sweet roll jelly-o muffin faworki biscuit. Marzipan marshmallow cake tiramisu caramels bear claw carrot cake cotton candy. Toffee danish sweet roll. Cookie topping powder toffee ice cream muffin dragée. Soufflé caramels apple pie chocolate cake cookie cake. Macaroon tiramisu halvah soufflé. Dessert toffee halvah chocolate cake bear claw."
   skills:
   - design
   - development
   - branding
   - ecommerce
   stack:
   - middleman
   - branding
   - design
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just use the full `project`object within your templates?

```
data.projects.each do |p|
  proxy "/work/#{p[:name].parameterize}.html", "work/template.html",
    :locals => { :p => p }
end
```

... should give you access to your project within *`http://0.0.0.0:4567/work/acme-website.html`*:

```
<ul>
 <li><%= p.name %></li>
 <li><%= p.client %></li>
</ul>
```

**Result:**

- Acme Website
- Acme Inc

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the YAML back into a Ruby object, then go from there:

```
require 'yaml'

doc = YAML.load(<<EOT)
---
-  name: Acme Website
  client: Acme Inc
  overview: "Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet wafer gummi bears pudding applicake. Jujubes brownie powder. Sweet roll powder gingerbread gummies. Cupcake ice cream sweet roll pie lollipop. Jelly-o jelly-o apple pie chupa chups jelly jujubes gingerbread. Icing carrot cake powder chupa chups. Pudding sweet roll jelly-o muffin faworki biscuit. Marzipan marshmallow cake tiramisu caramels bear claw carrot cake cotton candy. Toffee danish sweet roll. Cookie topping powder toffee ice cream muffin dragée. Soufflé caramels apple pie chocolate cake cookie cake. Macaroon tiramisu halvah soufflé. Dessert toffee halvah chocolate cake bear claw."
  skills:
  - design
  - development
  - branding
  - ecommerce
  stack:
  - middleman
  - branding
  - design
EOT

require 'pp'
pp doc
```

Which outputs:

```
[{"name"=>"Acme Website",
  "client"=>"Acme Inc",
  "overview"=>
  "Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet wafer gummi bears pudding applicake. Jujubes brownie powder. Sweet roll powder gingerbread gummies. Cupcake ice cream sweet roll pie lollipop. Jelly-o jelly-o apple pie chupa chups jelly jujubes gingerbread. Icing carrot cake powder chupa chups. Pudding sweet roll jelly-o muffin faworki biscuit. Marzipan marshmallow cake tiramisu caramels bear claw carrot cake cotton candy. Toffee danish sweet roll. Cookie topping powder toffee ice cream muffin dragée. Soufflé caramels apple pie chocolate cake cookie cake. Macaroon tiramisu halvah soufflé. Dessert toffee halvah chocolate cake bear claw.",
  "skills"=>["design", "development", "branding", "ecommerce"],
  "stack"=>["middleman", "branding", "design"]}]
```

That's an array of hashes. You can iterate over the returned array, and extract the embedded hashes and process them normally:

```
doc.each { |h|
  puts h['name']
  puts h['client']
}
```

Comment: maybe it's a trick question, the yaml is already loaded with `data.projects` i'm just not sure how to put the keys into the :locals hash.